# why the django filter query not accepting the passed values?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have below program that is suppose to execute `objects.filter` query on two columns and based that fetch the data of 3rd column.

```
class API(GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin, CreateModelMixin):
    serializer_class = [DummySerializer, ATSerializers]

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.org = None
        self.ent = None

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        org = request.data.get("org")
        ent = request.data.get("ent")

        self.org = org
        self.ent = ent

        if self.org is None or self.ent is None:

            return Response("Both fields are required to fetch token..", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        print("[QUERY SET] :", queryset)

        if not queryset:
            return Response("No matching records found.", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        lnk_token = list(queryset.values_list('link_token', flat=True))
        return Response({"lnk_tkn": lnk_token}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def get_queryset(self):
        org = self.org
        ent = self.ent
        print("this is get_queryset bloc")

        if org is None or ent is None:
            return tbl.objects.none()
        else:
            print(self.org, self.ent)
            filter_token = tbl.objects.filter(org=org, ent=ent)
            print(filter_token)
            lnk_token = filter_token.values_list('tkn', flat=True)

        return lnk_token

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if not queryset:
            return Response(f"Both IDs are the required fields.....")
        return Response(
            {
                "token": queryset
            }
        )
```

- I am receiving the values of `org` and `ent` from request body in my post method and passed onto the `get_queryset()` GET method.
- Then the values are supposed to be passed to

  filter_token = tbl.objects.filter(org=org, ent=ent)

That is when the code fails.

- Through print statement for org and ent at various location in both post method and and get_queryset() method  I could see that value coming in, but it is not getting passed to filter_token. I am not sure why. I am getting below error in post method where I have called get_queryset().

  "No matching records found." in my postman.
  below is the `print(filter_token)` output.

  <QuerySet []>
  [QUERY SET] : <QuerySet []>
- There are POST functionality in the post method that for now I have removed. Because I wanted to test the get_queryset() functionality before I restore the POST related stuffs there.
- The purpose of creating such function call structure is that when there is a POST method call then only those `org` and ent values would be passed to the POST API in request body. Hence, I wanted to execute the get_queryset() immediately within the POST for further data manipulation